# Is it proper to use "broke" in "Broke his feelings"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, figurative-language

> My colleague **broke his feelings**. (*English Syntax and Argumentation*,
>   Bas Aarts)

Aarts says this sentence is abnormal, because of the selectional restrictions: ‘feelings’ is abstract and not proper for the object of ‘broke.’ I can understand what he is saying. But is the case so strange enough to be selected by Aarts? We can say ‘The death of his wife broke him completely.’ Then why can’t we say like the example?

Comment: Strange. "break * feeling" has more than 25,000,000 hits on Google Books! Yes, maybe they are not entirely related with "break [pronoun] feeling", but 25,000,000 seems a notable number.

Comment: I'm glad that you can understand what "He broke his feelings" means. Perhaps you can explain it to me. I have no idea what it means out of context. Perhaps it can be used to express someone's disillusionment after learning that his wife or girlfriend was cheating on him, or that his boss was undermining his career by saying negative things behind his back, or that his best friend was using him because he had a fancy sports car. "He broke his feelings" means nothing to me. I'd have to ask whoever wrote or said such a thing to explain it in clear, simple, and easy-to-understand English.

Comment: "The death of his wife broke his **spirit**" is normal English, but "The death of his wife broke his **feelings**" is nonsense, in my not-so-humble opinion.

Comment: It does seem odd that you can have broken hearts, broken relationships, broken spirits, broken dreams, broken homes, broken promises, and broken treaties, but you can't have broken feelings, even though you _can_ have bruised feelings, hurt feelings, or even injured feelings. I find it especially peculiar that _feelings_ are tangible enough to be "bruised," but too abstract to be "broken," whereas _dreams_ can be broken or even crushed. I suppose it's all in how the idioms evolve.

Comment: @BillFranke, can you explain to me in clear, simple, and easy-to-understand English what a "broken heart" is? To me, had I never heard the phrase before, it seems entirely unintuitive. Nothing happens to anyone's blood-pumping muscle when they are emotionally injured. The only reason it makes sense to anyone now, and the reason you probably *can* explain it, is because we gave it a meaning a long time ago. Had "broken feelings" been given a meaning a long time ago, you'd have no problem understanding it.

Comment: @Ken: I think Bill is saying the same thing you are, just in a different way. Without an [established precedent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/broken-hearted), it would be hard to ascertain the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: @KenB: "A broken heart" is a simple metaphor. "A broken feeling" is  an absurdity, as are "broken feelings", and the sentence "He broke his feelings" is meaningless because **it's not idiomatic** and isn't analogous to broken fingers, arms, or other body parts, so there's no metaphor that leaps to mind. I'm not a linguistic egalitarian. For language to be useful, interesting, and meaningful, it has to have all three qualities.

Comment: @BillFranke as JR and others have said, what about phrases such as "broken dreams" or "broken promises"? There's nothing concrete about those either. Do you find these to be nonsense? Honestly curious, not trying to be provocative.

Comment: Do you think the only reason the sentence is incorrect because it disagrees with the way we’ve been using it for years (as in idiom)? I’m sensing that the direct object (feelings) is not able to take the action of the verb. But then again, why not? I also can’t find any rule stating an abstract noun can’t be used as an object of a transitive verb (broke). Very interesting question btw.

Comment: It would shatter my feelings if this question didn't get a lot of upvotes.

Comment: @KenB: No, I find "broken dreams" and "broken promises" to be idiomatic English phrases, not absurdities. The notion that "broken feelings" is wrong because feelings are abstract instead of concrete is absurd, however. That's an ad hoc explanation, a rationalization that attempts to explain based on the commentor's ignorance. The only reason it's wrong is that it's not idiomatic and not heard because it's not used. Historical accident or not is irrelevant, IMHO.

Comment: @BillFranke Could it not be argued that everything was non-idiomatic" at some point, and that the evolution of language demands the usage of non-idiomatic phrases in order to determine what should and shouldn't become an idiom? Is it really wrong to use an uncommon expression simply because it is uncommon?

Comment: @KenB: It's wrong only if you want to be understood. If you're an innovative native speaker coining neologisms galore (The Bard was), then your ear will help your create art. If you're a typical native speaker, then it won't. If you're an EFL student, you shouldn't be encouraged to use unusual expressions. I shouldn't have to say any more than that. And soon the moderation software will ask us to cut the discussion go to chat, which I don't do.

Comment: @Ken: You can use an uncommon expression, but you can't expect everyone will necessarily come to the same conclusion about what that expression might mean unless or until it becomes an established idiom. We know what [sour grapes](http://www.onelook.com/?w=sour+grapes&ls=a) are, and we all know what it means to [cry over spilt milk](http://www.onelook.com/?w=dont+cry+over+spilt+milk), but if I said, "That's like putting wine in the waterbed," what would that mean? We can guess, but... (Sorry to keep answering your questions to Bill, but I'm finding them irresistably interesting questions.)

Comment: @BillFranke That's a thoroughly satisfying answer. Good point on not encouraging EFL/ESL students to use non-idiomatic answers. J.R., thanks, I thought so. :) Love the input.

Comment: The reason you can say broke heart or broke him but not broke his feelings, is because as @BillFranke was saying those are analogs to something tangible. Even a promise or a dream is something tangible. A dream while an idea is not abstract. If I dream of going to Africa someday you have a very concrete idea of what I want to do. If I promise to take out the trash, again I give concrete knowledge of what is supposed to happen. I can't give you a concrete picture of my feelings, they are subjective to each individual person. Since you can't attach it to something tangible it can't be broken.

Comment: @ryan: If feelings aren't tangible, then how can they bruise? Moreover, I disagree that a "broken heart" refers to something tangible. "Heart" in that case refers to the center of emotions, not the organ that pumps blood through your body. A broken heart is not the same thing as a broken vase; a broken _spirit_ is no more tangible than a broken _feeling_, but the former has meaning while the latter does not.

Comment: @J.R. bruise is another way of saying hurt or even misused. And a broken heart can cause real pain. http://www.genconnect.com/relationships/study-a-broken-heart-causes-real-pain/ It is also metaphorical in that it is comparing to something that does have a concrete representation in real life. As for Spirit, you can see Fumblefingers answer for that, or think about the fact that historically most English speakers have been Christian and they do indeed consider the spirit to be something tangible and real.

Comment: @ryan: As Bill said, this is because one expression is idiomatic, and the other isn't, as opposed to one being more "tangible". When something tangible is broken, we can pick up the pieces or see the crack, otherwise feelings could be broken as easily as spirits or hearts. Non-tangible things _can_ be broken, and tangible things can be broken in intangible ways: _break a sweat, break a news story, break a record, break a horse, break the bank, break the ice_, as well as _broken strides, broken ranks, broken plays, broken verse, broken habits, broken spells_ – I think I'll break it off here.

Comment: @J.R., I can see it more like a matter of unit. Can you break a feeling? Can you imagine a feeling in 2 pieces? When you say break a heart you can even draw a heart in 2 pieces. Maybe he meant abstract in that sense, since you can not possible imagine a feeling in 2 pieces. And when you hurt my feelings, you really mean something like, you hurt my sensitivity. You never really imagine the "feeling" as hurt, you imagine the "feeler" as hurt. Feelings are more of an action than a noun, so it can be disrupted but not broken.

Comment: @Dzyann - That's an interesting thought, but I don't find a dream much easier to visualize in two pieces. Yet somehow "Boulevard Of Broken Dreams" doesn't sound as odd as "Boulevard Of Broken Feelings". It's hard to figure out, but your theory has given me another angle to consider.

Comment: @J.R. I find hard to image a Dream in two pieces, but I do imagine it as a Unit, while feelings are more of a flow. At least that is how I imagine it. All these abstract things are very hard to imagine really, but I feel that there is more to it that simply an historical accident or a matter of historical usage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe "break" is used metaphorically in "broken heart" and "broken man", and these metaphors have long since become fixed in language.  We're used to hearing them so much we don't even think of them as metaphors.

So why not "broken feelings"?  I believe it's simply a *historical accident*.  It's plausible to me that the collocation "broken feelings" could have become just as common as "a broken heart", even though it never did.  In other words, I don't believe there *is* any real analysis to make of it.

I could be wrong, of course.  But it's hard to say--we can't re-run history and see what different words and collocations we end up with, so it's not the sort of thing we can experiment with and determine empirically.  It's just a matter of *what makes sense*--and what makes sense to *me* is that it's a simple accident.

Comment: As Aarts said (perhaps implied), "man" and "heart" are both physical, concrete objects, whereas "feelings" is too abstract to be practical. On the other hand, "spirit" is more abstract, but I think we equate a man's "spirit" with the man himself, or perhaps with culturally founded images of spirits as angels, people-shaped beings, etc, which might make it just concrete enough to visualize, making it more useable.

Comment: @KenB How about broken dreams?  Do you believe dreams are more concrete than feelings?

Comment: Then again, as @J.R. points out above, you *can* break promises and dreams, each of which I would consider to be at about the same level of abstraction as feelings. So I really have to agree with you that it's a simple happenstance of history.

Comment: To "break someone's **spirit**" is idiomatic English. To "break someone's **feelings**" is not. It may be possible to say something like "You **broke the feeling** when you hesitated", but that means "You **ruined the {ambiance / atmosphere}** when you hesitated".

Comment: @snailplane see my comment above, dreams ***are*** in fact more concrete then feelings.

Comment: @ryan I would say "in my opinion" rather than "in fact" if I were you; you can make that argument, but it's all a bit fuzzy and just-so to my mind.  I'm still not convinced there is any logic to it, let alone logic strong enough to hang the "fact" hat on.

Answer (score 10):

I do not recall ever hearing a fluent English speaker say "broke his feelings".

It is a common idiom to say that someone "broke his/her heart". Typically this is said if a wife or girlfriend or husband or boyfriend terminates a relationship. It is also commonly said if someone close to a person disappoints him in some extreme way, like "When he learned that his son had become a thief and a killer, it broke his heart."

It is also common to say that someone "hurt his feelings". This is used for a disappointment or offense on a much smaller scale than "broke his heart". Like, "When she didn't show up for their first date, it hurt his feelings." "When he learned that his son had failed a history test, it hurt his feelings."

I don't know any logical reason why we say "broke his heart" but not "hurt his heart", and "hurt his feelings" but not "broke his feelings". But that's the nature of idioms. Some phrases just come to be commonly accepted, and others ... don't.

Regarding 25 million hits for "break * feelings": I checked out the first two pages and didn't see any that were "break his feelings" or "break her feelings". Rather, there were many other words in between, like "When she broke up with him, it hurt his feelings". Finding such a high number for that pair of words doesn't surprise me at all: People routinely talk their feelings when someone breaks up with them.

Comment: There are some very interesting excerpts among those millions of hits, like this one: _To portray a woman caught in this swirl of emotions, Hunter had to break the feelings into manageable, actable chunks._ But even this isn't really talking about _broken feelings_, it's more like _dissected feelings_ in this context, and that use of the word _broken_ could apply to feelings, ideas, freedoms and liberties, or any other abstract concept.

Comment: My late Taiwanese wife was always saying "Oh, that hurt my heart".

Comment: @J.R. Sure. You could say of anything, "He broke X into manageable chunks." That's literal: You break some large collection up into smaller pieces.

Comment: Yes - that's why it's worth perusing the hits: to examine context. After awhile, one might say (for example): maybe we don't _normally_ talk about "broken feelings," but I suppose we _could_ talk about "broken feelings," if we were talking about breaking them down into individual _pieces_ (like an actor might need to do, to be persuasive on camera or on stage).

Answer (score 5):

From Google Books:

> [hurt my feelings](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22broke%20my%20feelings%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22hurt%20my%20feelings%22&oq=%22hurt%20my%20feelings%22&gs_l=serp.3...52330.58855.3.59112.30.30.0.0.0.0.84.1614.30.30.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.GyqL6J4BsBc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 370,000 hits
>    [broke my heart](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22broke%20my%20feelings%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22broke%20my%20heart%22&oq=%22broke%20my%20heart%22&gs_l=serp.3...10850.14185.2.14631.13.13.0.0.0.0.92.710.13.13.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.M15S_81s9Ws&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 122,000 hits
>    [broke his spirit](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22broke%20my%20spirit%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22broke%20his%20spirit%22&oq=%22broke%20his%20spirit%22&gs_l=serp.3...16819.17881.1.18553.5.5.0.0.0.0.78.249.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.5.serp.b1uOzfn2DsI&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZGU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1296&bih=859) 65,300 hits
>    [broke my feelings](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22broke%20my%20feelings%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 1 hit

That single instance is actually the reported speech of a child, in a book with the equally "ungrammatical" title [Nice on My Feelings](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xm9MQgFlUAAC&q=%22broke%20my%20feelings%22&dq=%22broke%20my%20feelings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iBQ-UajTL47B7AaWxoDoDA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA) (there are *no* relevant instances of *broke **his** feelings*).

So one justification for Aarts saying "this sentence is abnormal" is simply the fact that *people don't say it*. As regards the "selectional restrictions" justification, I would put it like this:

Your (real or metaphorical) *heart* is something that can be seen as whole and functional, so it can be "broken". Equally, with your *spirit*, it's a reference to your vivacity/determination - which can also be "broken", so it doesn't function properly any more. But *feelings* are always there (in fact you'd probably have *more* of them if someone broke your heart); they're not sufficiently organised or functional to be described as "broken", no matter what happens to them.

Comment: +1 for actually getting to the root of why some of these idioms became common and why others didn't.

Comment: @ryan: There's not always an identifiable reason why certain idiomatic usages become established, while other equally credible ones don't. But I felt I should answer in this case because it didn't seem quite right for both the other answers to be effectively saying *it's a meaningless historical accident of language evolution*. You've only got to consider *"He broke my concentration"* to see that we like using the word metaphorically. But the thing that's broken must previously have been something *whole, integrated,* and *functional*.

Comment: +1 for getting to the root of the matter with _broke my concentration_. If _concentration_ can be broken, surely _happiness_ could be, too – but, for whatever reason, we [just don't say it that way](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ruined+my+happiness%2Cwrecked+my+happiness%2Cbroke+my+happiness&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah, I agree we're getting closer to "inexplicable, random" idiomatic usages. But bearing in mind [**destroyed** my happiness](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shattered+my+happiness%2Cwrecked+my+happiness%2Cbroke+my+happiness%2Cdestroyed+my+happiness&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) trumps all others I can think of, might it not be that "concentration" is a mental state *with a purpose* (that can be *broken*, so it doesn't "work" any more), whereas "happiness" is just something you have like having (it can't be *broken, non-functional*). Maybe.

Comment: I don't suppose that idioms are random. Whoever was the first person to say something normally had some coherent thought in mind. (I'm sure some idioms that sound non-sensical would, upon in-depth investigation, prove to be non-sensical.) The thing about idioms is that, very often, we routinely use a certain combination of words but a very similar and arguably quite parallel combination of words is never used. Like here: "Broke his heart" and "Hurt his feelings" are common, people say them all the time. I can't think of any logical reason why we should not say "hurt his heart". But we don't.

Comment: @Jay: I'm not so sure about that. I'll admit that [pained my heart](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pained+my+heart%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) sounds much more natural to me than [it hurt my heart](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it+hurt+my+heart%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but according to Google Books the latter would actually seem to be *more* common. Perhaps it's just become more dated/literary.

Answer (score 1):

Also, an interesting aspect in "My colleague broke his feelings" is that HE did it to HIMSELF. If the correct form is eg "break one's heart", I still can't break it to myself, but something must break it to me. Similarly, I suppose, we can't say "I broke my spirit" but have to say that "something broke my spirit" etc. Am I right?

Comment: Basically, yes. Though you certainly might say, "When I failed to accomplish X, it broke my spirit." In a real-world sense, you broke your spirit yourself. But still, the phrasing is that it was the event that did it. I've never heard someone say "I broke my heart" or "I broke my spirit". It doesn't sound odd to say "I broke my own spirit", but I can't think of a case where I heard someone say that, either.

Comment: Yes I noticed this. It certainly sounds reflexive from the syntax but doesn't really make sense as a reflexive verb.

Answer (score 1):

Although "broke his feelings" is just as logical than "hurt his feelings" or "broke his heart" it is simply non-idiomatic.